# Python Numpy appending multiple lists from objects

Tags: python, numpy

I am calling an object several times that is returning a numpy list:

```
for x in range(0,100):
        d = simulation3()

d = [0, 1, 2, 3]
d = [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

..and many more

I want to take each list and append it to a 2D array.

`final_array = [[0, 1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6, 7]`...and so forth]

I tried creating an empty array (`final_array = np.zeros(4,4)`) and appending it but the values are appending after the `4X4 matrix` is created.

Can anyone help me with this?  thank you!

Comment: `final_array = [simulation3() for _ in range(100)]`?

Comment: @Alexander maybe wrap it in a `np.stack`?

Comment: From my understanding, `simulation3` returns a list of four random numbers.  The `final_array` desired result is simply a list of lists per the example.  Yes, `np.stack([simulation3() for _ in range(100)])` would result in a 100x4 np.ndarray if that is what the OP wants.

Comment: `np.zeros((4,4))` is not an 'empty' array; not in the sense that `[]` is an empty list.  In general it is better to collect the objects in a list, and do one `concatenate` at the end.  Iterative concatenates are slow, and hard to initialize right (you have to understand array dimensions well).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.fromiter` to create an array from an iterable. Since, by default, this function only works with scalars, you can use `itertools.chain` to help:

```
np.random.seed(0)

from itertools import chain

def simulation3():
    return np.random.randint(0, 10, 4)

n = 5
d = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(simulation3() for _ in range(5)), dtype='i')
d.shape = 5, 4

print(d)

array([[5, 0, 3, 3],
       [7, 9, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 7, 6],
       [8, 8, 1, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

But this is relatively inefficient. NumPy performs best with fixed size arrays. If you know the size of your array in advance, you can define an empty array and update rows sequentially. See the [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076711/9209546) described by @norok2.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple way to do it in numpy , the easiest way is to use vstack like this :

for Ex :

```
#you have these array you want to concat

d1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
d2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
d3 = [4, 5, 6, 7]

#initialize your variable with zero raw 
X = np.zeros((0,4))

#then each time you call your function use np.vstack like this :
X = np.vstack((np.array(d1),X))
X = np.vstack((np.array(d2),X))
X = np.vstack((np.array(d2),X))

# and finally you have your array like below
#array([[4., 5., 6., 7.],
#       [4., 5., 6., 7.],
#       [0., 1., 2., 3.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution depends on the numbers / sizes you are dealing with.
My favorite solution (which only works if you already know the size of the final result) is to initialize the array which will contain your results and then fill each you could initialize your result and then fill it using views.
This the most memory efficient solution.

If you do not know the size of the final result, then you are better off by generating a list of lists, which can be converted (or stacked) as a NumPy array at the end of the process.

Here are some examples, where `gen_1d_list()` is used to generate some random numbers to mimic the result of `simulate3()` (meaning that in the following code, you should replace `gen_1d_list(n, dtype)` with `simulate3()`):

- `stacking1()` implements the filling using views
- `stacking2()` implements the list generation and **converting** to NumPy array
- `stacking3()` implements the list generation and **stacking** to NumPy array
- `stacking4()` implements the dynamic modification of a NumPy array using `vstack()` as proposed earlier.

```
import numpy as np

def gen_1d_list(n, dtype=int):
    return list(np.random.randint(1, 100, n, dtype))

def stacking1(n, m, dtype=int):
    arr = np.empty((n, m), dtype=dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        arr[i] = gen_1d_list(m, dtype)
    return arr

def stacking2(n, m, dtype=int):
    items = [gen_1d_list(m, dtype) for i in range(n)]
    arr = np.array(items)
    return arr

def stacking3(n, m, dtype=int):
    items = [gen_1d_list(m, dtype) for i in range(n)]
    arr = np.stack(items, dtype)
    return arr

def stacking4(n, m, dtype=int):
    arr = np.zeros((0, m), dtype=dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        arr = np.vstack((gen_1d_list(m, dtype), arr))
    return arr
```

Time-wise, `stacking1()` and `stacking2()` are more or less equally fast, while `stacking3()` and `stacking4()` are slower (and, in proportion, much slower for small size inputs).

Some numbers, for small size inputs:

```
n, m = 4, 10
%timeit stacking1(n, m)
# 15.7 µs ± 182 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit stacking2(n, m)
# 14.2 µs ± 141 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit stacking3(n, m)
# 22.7 µs ± 282 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit stacking4(n, m)
# 31.8 µs ± 270 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and for larger size inputs:

```
n, m = 4, 1000000
%timeit stacking1(n, m)
# 344 ms ± 1.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit stacking2(n, m)
# 350 ms ± 1.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit stacking3(n, m)
# 370 ms ± 2.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit stacking4(n, m)
# 369 ms ± 3.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```